# How can I change the list of enum options displayed in the inspector?

Tags: unity, c#

I have an array of enums:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EnumsInInspector : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public EnumType[] myEnums = new EnumType[3];

    public enum EnumType
    {
        A,
        B,
        C
    }
}
```

I want it so that if the enum at index 0 is B, then when selecting the enum at index 1, only A and C are options, and B is no longer available.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to write a custom inspector for this type. Filtering enum options based on previous list entries isn't a built-in behaviour.

Comment: Specifically a [PropertyDrawer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html). I can probably throw something together this evening if you don't have it figured out by then. I expect you to self answer this and get all the up-votes though.

Comment: Sorry, I put some time in on this, but have to get to work on some other things. Perhaps later in the week.

Comment: @Byte56 thanks :-) I've put quite a bit of time into it myself, but moreso to learn the basics of ProperyDrawers. Not quite to the level of solving this problem yet.